# Pairing multiple nodes - script for reading enodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, enode

I want to pair 20 nodes. But going through each node and its enode information and copying it into my staticNodes.json seems like a lot of work. Is there any way how I can automate this prcocess? Or at least write the enode information to a text file, so that i can collect all the textfiles later and just parse them?

Thank you all!